# magento 2 cron failed scheduled at 12 am

Tags: magento2, cron

Please check the below code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipifF.png

I have scheduled cron job for 12am midnight.
But I cannot see cron job scheduled at 12 am.

If I schedule cron job for in next 15 mins it will be scheduled but it wont be excuted by its own.

If I schedule cron job for * * * * * it works perfectly.

Please help and thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is simple solution for this.

First check cron installed or not using crontab -e

Make sure the below line is present in it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqYkv.png

If this is not present,kindly run below command:

php bin/magento cron:install

Then you are good to go.
Cron jobs will schedule by its own..

Thanks